# Cron task for Rails application (elasticsearch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, cron

I'd like to start gem elasticsearch if it's not running in my Rails app. I don't want to use any other gems to do it. 
So I created file start.sh:

```
if pgrep -u sth java; then
   /home/sth/sth/attractions/elasticsearch-1.6.0/bin/elasticsearch
fi
```

and I placed it in crontab:

```
* * * * * /home/sth/sth/attractions/start.sh
```

The script is not working and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Cron is not the way to do this under Linux, the init system can help you here :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service.html